# Send SMS from BB10 using Android SDK

Tags: android, sms, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

Is there any way to send SMS text messages on BlackBerry 10 using the Android SDK, since according to [BlackBerry documentation for Android apps](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_hardware_features.html) SMSManager and SMSMessage hardware features are not supported?

Comment: The link in the question is broken. This link may be better: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupported_api_jellybean_hardware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this only works on Dev Alpha devices running 10.9.10.35 or later. The following intent to launches the standard messaging app, including a target phone number and body text:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
intent.putExtra("address", adress);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

[The documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html) seems to suggest that this is disallowed, but nevertheless it works:

> Android applications cannot provide system-wide services to the rest
>   of the device. E.g:
>
> - Dialing services (handling android.intent.action.ACTION_DIAL)
> - Viewing capabilities (system-wide handing of android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW)
> - Data sharing capabilities (android.intent.action.ACTION_SEND)

I discovered the native package name that handles the intent by querying the components that accepts it, which revealed:

```
com.rim.messaging.NativeSmsMms
```

Sure enough, launching it works as expected:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        "com.rim.messaging",
        "com.rim.messaging.NativeSmsMms"));
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Beware that the Android version is not present and hence the following intent will not work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        "com.android.mms",
        "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"));
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I initially thought this wasn't possible after testing on our Dev Alpha device, but evidently it was originally shipped without the *Text Messages* app. Go figure.

Comment: Intresting report, thank you for your answer my friend. I will do some tests, when I have a bb10 device and if you are right I'll mark the question as solved. Thank you again.

Comment: I just did another test using the contact list, and also there nothing happens. I'll test again in the morning.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
  intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);

Just created an intent that way, and I run the code on a device and I didn't had any errors, I didn't had any SIM card to fully test it decently thought. Could you give it a shot in my place?

Comment: I accidentally swapped the component names in the post above; corrected that. Android accepts the first and third solution, BB10 only crashes on the last. I'm testing with a SIM in just a moment.

Comment: No, the SIM card appears to have no effect. A software update is available for our Dev Alpha. I will follow up if I get the green light to update it.

Comment: I contacted RIM, and while they couldn't responded concerning the specific issue, they mentioned that messaging should work on the Dev Alpha device. It doesn't, but I haven't gotten around to updating. Will do soon.

Comment: After the upgrade to 10.9.10.35, the built-in contact app started working! Even better news is that I found one RIM-specific method and one generic way to get the intent to fire correctly! I've updated my answer to reflect my revised findings.

Comment: Just bought a real device, and your code works decently. Thank you.